# how to install vuetify without having problem of TypeError: child.on is not a function?

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuetify.js, nvm

i am getting this error:

> 

Installing vue-cli-plugin-vuetify...

ERROR  TypeError: child.on is not a function
TypeError: child.on is not a function
at D:\Users\beniv\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.13.2\node_modules@vue\cli\lib\util\executeCommand.js:136:11
at new Promise ()
at executeCommand (D:\Users\beniv\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.13.2\node_modules@vue\cli\lib\util\executeCommand.js:61:10)
at PackageManager.runCommand (D:\Users\beniv\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.13.2\node_modules@vue\cli\lib\util\ProjectPackageManager.js:351:18)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async PackageManager.add (D:\Users\beniv\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.13.2\node_modules@vue\cli\lib\util\ProjectPackageManager.js:415:12)
at async add (D:\Users\beniv\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.13.2\node_modules@vue\cli\lib\add.js:58:5)

> 

what i can do?

i'm using this vue version:

> 

C:\Users\beniv\done>npm list vue
done@0.1.0 C:\Users\beniv\done
+-- @vue/cli-plugin-babel@4.5.15
| `-- @vue/babel-preset-app@4.5.15 |`   -- vue@2.6.14 deduped
`-- vue@2.6.14

> 

and this npm version:

> 

C:\Users\beniv\done>npm --version
8.1.2

> 

Comment: Hello, please take care about how you format your question. Also, give details about what you did to start your project: a tutorial, a Github readme, a post... It's hard to help without knowing what you already did.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.